# Внешний доступ к gitlab

Tags: nginx, centos, gitlab

Скачал и настроил GitLab по данной инструкции https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos6

В `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` сделал такие изменения:

```
#external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com'
external_url 'http://123.456.789.012'
```

Но при переходе по данному адресу главная страница не отображается, а лишь появляется страница приветствия от nginx (странно только что там говорится про Debian, а сама система CentOS):

> Welcome to nginx on Debian!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working on Debian. Further configuration is required.

```
# gitlab-ctl status
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 18016) 4466s; run: log: (pid 16399) 5362s
run: logrotate: (pid 21962) 866s; run: log: (pid 16466) 5356s
run: nginx: (pid 18030) 4465s; run: log: (pid 16398) 5362s
run: postgresql: (pid 18038) 4465s; run: log: (pid 16171) 5410s
run: redis: (pid 18040) 4464s; run: log: (pid 16092) 5416s
run: sidekiq: (pid 18052) 4463s; run: log: (pid 16349) 5368s
run: unicorn: (pid 18069) 4462s; run: log: (pid 16304) 5374s
```

Системного же nginx нет, в `/etc/nginx`. Подключение клиента к серверу происходит по сети Интернет, а не через, скажем, VirtualBox.

Как правильно настроить внешний адрес для gitlab?

---

**Обновлено**

При попытке подключения с клиента из внешней сети, после добавления порта в external_url:

```
$ lynx http://88.88.88.88:9009/

Looking up 88.88.88.88:9009
Making HTTP connection to 88.88.88.88:9009
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.
```

При попытке подключения с сервера к самому себе:

```
$ lynx 127.0.0.1:9009

Looking up 127.0.0.1 first
Looking up 127.0.0.1:9009
Making HTTP connection to 127.0.0.1:9009
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Allowing this cookie.
Data transfer complete
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Using http://88.88.88.88:9009/users/sign_in
Looking up 88.88.88.88:9009
Making HTTP connection to 88.88.88.88:9009
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://127.0.0.1:9009/
```

Comment: М, Omnibus! Скорее всего, это **не тот nginx**. А нужный не запустился, ибо порт занят.

Comment: опишите в вопросе, как ваш компьютер подключен к интернету.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не совсем понял, что именно нужно описать, но обновил вопрос.

Comment: @edem, под «вашим компьютером» я подразумевал ту машину (реальную или виртуальную), на которой вы установили и настроили gitlab. у неё непосредственно на одном из сетевых интерфейсов используется ip-адрес, по которому вы подключаетесь? кстати, откуда вы пробуете подключаться — непосредственно с этой машины, с другой машины в той же локальной сети, с компьютера, независимо подключенного к интернету?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, ip тот же к которому подключаюсь, и клиент подключается совсем из другой сети.

Comment: нужный вам nginx скорее всего валяется в /opt

Comment: @edem, посмотрите процессы, которые слушают порты 80 и 9009: `$ sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP:80 -iTCP:9009 -sTCP:LISTEN` (в выдаче будут и pid-ы процессов в т.ч.). узнать, где находится исполнимый файл, зная pid, можно, например, так: `$ sudo file /proc/сюда-подставить-pid/exe`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ничего не выдаёт в результате.

Comment: @edem, не может быть. какой-то процесс ведь отвечает на порту 127.0.0.1:9009. // пожалуйста, хватит играть в прятки. приложите к вопросу вывод: `ip a; ip r; sudo iptables-save; ps aux`. и selinux отключите, если включен.

Comment: @D-side Ваша догадка была в яблочко.

Comment: @edem я точно помню, что видел ещё один такой случай здесь же, но не сумел откопать конкретный вопрос. Вероятно, он удалён. А жаль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что на 80-м порту был запущен другой nginx, который и отображался при переходе на сайт. Возможные решения:

1. Отключить первый nginx, тем самым освободив 80-й порт.
2. Или изменить `external_url 'http://123.456.789.012'` на вариант с указанием другого порта `external_url 'http://123.456.789.012:8888'`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перевести порт на `external_url 'http://123.456.789.012:9009'`, не забудьте выполнить `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: Обновил вопрос.